# Como enviar dados do form com evento onChange para php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom dia pessoal, alguem pode me ajudar com o seguinte problema,
eu quero enviar dados de dois campos, um do tipo texto e outro do tipo select option e quero quando eu clicar na selecao fazer o post. ai esta o meu codigo

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="">

            <input type="text" name="nome" onChange="Enviar(this.value);" >
            <select name="sexo" onchange="">
                <option value="">selecionar...</option>
                <option value="M">M</option>
                <option value="F">F</option>
            </select>

        </form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
            function getState() {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "pag.php",
                    data: $("#form").serialize(),
                });
            }
        </script>
```

E na pagina pag.php

PHP

Mas nao esta dar certo

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você não está chamando a função descrita.Você deve adicionar a função a seu "onchange" da seleção.

```
<select name="sexo" onchange="getState()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode chamar a função assim também:

```
$(document).on('change', "[name='sexo']", function(){
   getState();
});
```